# Example of $\mu_1,\mu_2$ where $\mu_{1}(F)=\mu_{2}(F)\, \forall F \in \mathcal{F}$ but $\mu_1\ne \mu_2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $$\mu_{1}:\sigma(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow [0,1]$$ $$\mu_{2}:\sigma(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow [0,1] $$ are probability measures. And $\forall F \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mu_{1}(F)=\mu_{2}(F)$. But $\mu_{1}\neq \mu_{2} $. I need to give an example of $\mu_{1}, \mu_{2}$.

I've spend much time and have no idea. Please give me any hints...

Comment: I think you should specify some requirements on $\mathcal{F}$, because otherwise we can just take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take sets $A = \{1,2\},B=\{1,3\}$ be a subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $\mathcal F = \{A,B\}$. Then define $\mu_1,\mu_2$ such that:

$$\mu_1(\{2\}) = \mu_1(\{3\}) = \frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$ \mu_2(\{1\}) = \mu_2(\{4\})  = \frac{1}{2} $$

Then $\mu_1(A) = \mu_1(B) = \frac{1}{2} = \mu_2(A) = \mu_2(B)$

But $\mu_1(\{1\}) = 0 \not = \frac{1}{2} =  \mu_2(\{1\}) $

Comment: How do you define $\mu_1(A)$ if it's only specified for $\{1\}$ and $\{3\}$? sorry if it's too basic.

Comment: Note that probability measures satisfy $\mu_1(\Omega) = 1$. In our case $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$. By saying that $\mu_1(\{2\}) = \mu_1(\{3\}) = \frac{1}{2}$, we automaticly assume that $\mu_1(\{1\}) = \mu_1(\{4\}) = 0$ ( it cannot be greater than $0$ ). Then $\mu_1(A) = \mu_1(\{1\}) + \mu_1(\{2\}) = 0 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly with $\mu_2$.